# Javascript get element which handler was attached to

Tags: javascript

When an onclick event is fired on a element how do you get the element the event was attached to from the event object (opposed to the .target element that was clicked on)?

Answer (score 2):

You could access the [`currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) :

> `currentTarget` - Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to **the element the event handler has been attached** to as opposed to `event.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Comment: Weird, I am getting null for currentTarget in chrome?

Comment: @frankastin That's odd. I'm using Chrome as well, and it worked here - http://jsfiddle.net/f8yymus6/