# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined at myFun (main.js:3

Tags: javascript, typeerror

This is my Html code aur structure

```
 <body>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
```

This is my code i want to change the div  background colour when i mouseover the div its showing me the error main.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined at myFun (main.js:3) at main.js:6 this is my code

```
const way = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        function myFun() { 
            way.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <= way.length; i++) {
            way[i].addEventListener('mouseover', myFun);
        }
```

Comment: `way` is a NodeList. Not the element that you clicked. You can either use `this`, or add the `event` parameter to your `myFun()` function and use `event.currentTarget`. See [Javascript get element which handler was attached to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923337/javascript-get-element-which-handler-was-attached-to). Side note: you have an [off-by-one error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939869/what-is-an-off-by-one-error-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 0):

Change the js to

```
const way = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

function myFun(box) {
  box.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}

for (let i = 0; i < way.length; i++) {
  way[i].addEventListener("mouseover", () => myFun(way[i]));
}
```

Using `let` instead of `var` will make it easier to handle closure in the callback function of `addEventListener()` i.e. `() => myFunc(way[i])`

The test expression of the for loop should use `<` instead of `<=` because there is the index starts from `0` so there are only `Array.length - 1` elements hence `Array[Array.length]` will be undefined.

And lastly in your code, in myFunc() `way` is the collection of HTML elements returned by `getElementsByClassNames()`, so you need to pass the element whose `backgroundColor` you want to change.